# Se borra el archivo al cambiar de controlador

Tags: swift2, xcode, ios8

Tengo una app en donde guardo un archivo en un metodo llamado enviar imagen y hay guarda y si verifico la existencia del archivo me retorna true y todo bien segun parece, pero luego de acuerdo a unos criterios se debe disparar otro metodo en este metodo se debe buscar ese archivo que se guardo anteriormente y se debe enviar a un servicio Web pero cuando verifico la existencia de este retorna false que ya no existe, ¿sera por que este ultimo metodo esta en otro controller? ¿por que no tengo idea? 
este es el codigo de guardar el archivo: 
 let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

```
    // Imagen y imagen en formato NSData
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imgLugar.image!, 1.0) {

        // Creamos la URL final
        let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath).URLByAppendingPathComponent(nombreImg)

        do {
            // Guardamos imagen
           print("\(documentsPath)/\(nombreImg)")
           try print("guardo: \(imageData.writeToURL(filePath, options: []))")
             let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
            let imgString = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath("\(documentsPath)/\(nombreImg)")
            print("existe: \(imgString))")
            let rut = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/80420879-6E5A-4211-8014-EAFAA9273897/Documents/img_49_24"
            print("existeAnt: \(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(rut))")
        } catch {

            print(error)

        }

    }
```

y este es el codigo en otro controllador en donde busco la imagen que se guardo anteriormente esta en el appdelegate:

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

```
            let imgString = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(String(usuarioLugar.uslImagen))
            print(imgString)
```

la ruta es la siguiente esta igual en ambos metodos: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/80420879-6E5A-4211-8014-EAFAA9273897/Documents/img_49_24 el fileExistsAtPath en el primer metodo retorna true y en el segundo false. ¿que puedo hacer o a que se debe esto?

Answer (score 1):

Para guardar una imagen usar:

```
func save() {
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    print(documentsPath)
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgLugar.image!, 1.0) {

        let imageLocalURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath).URLByAppendingPathComponent("img.jpeg")
        imageData.writeToURL(imageLocalURL, atomically: true)
    }

    let existeImg = exists("img.jpeg")
    print(existeImg)
}
```

Y para verificar si una imagen está guardado podes usar:

```
func exists(name: String) -> Bool {
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let imageLocalURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath).URLByAppendingPathComponent(name)
    var error: NSError?
    let imagenExiste = imageLocalURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(&error)
    if imagenExiste && error == nil {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

En tu código hay paths fijos (e.g. `rut`) y métodos que se le llaman dentro de un String interpolation, otra vez dentro de una sentencia `print` (e.g. `try print("guardo: \(imageData.writeToURL(filePath, options: []))")`).
Los paths fijos y absolutos no son una buena idea porque cambian, usar `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` cómo en el ejemplo anterior.
Y los métodos en String interpolations son una mala idea porque son confusos, peor todavía dentro de sentencias `print`.